# how do i send a variable in the url in javascript

Tags: javascript

i know how to do it in php:

but how would i do that in javascript.

thanks =)

Comment: The same way: you append it to the URL.

Comment: show us how you would do it in PHP and someone might suggest a Javascript solution.

Comment: in php i would just do <a href = 'index.php?id=$i">link</a>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your answer is going to depend heavily on your other requirements. I'd probably send it as a search query, IE `?key=value`, and then you can access that with `window.location.search`

Answer (score 0):

You may need to clarify your answer but if you had a url variable such as

`var myuri = 'http://www.stackoverflow.com'`

then you can simply add your variable with `myuri + variablename` if your variable is a string. Concatenating is very easy.

If you are looking to send a variable in the URL in Javascript through something like a query string, again you can simply control that with appending string parameters onto the string of the page's location via `window.location`

EDIT: Now that I've seen your example, you have to realize that you're changing your paradigm from server-side to client-side programming language. Whereas PHP can be embedded into a page, you'll need to change to an event-driven model for Javascript to work. The equivalent of your example in JavaScript would be something like

`<a href="#" onclick="addVariable(i);">Hello world</a>`

and then in your javascript file you would need to make sure that `i` is set before you click the link, and then the function would work as follows (in a Javascript file):

```
function addVariable(queryStringVariable)
{
    window.location = "http://www.someurl.com/page?" + queryStringVariable;
};
```