# send php variable value via javascript in url

Tags: php, javascript

I've read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5751774/how-do-i-send-a-variable-in-the-url-in-javascript)([how do i send a variable in the url in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5751774/how-do-i-send-a-variable-in-the-url-in-javascript)), but can't get it to work.  I must add that I don't know javascript at all.  I'm trying to open an new "printer friendly" page in php, but in order for that I need to send the userid with the url, my code looks like this:

**Page1**

```
<?php
session_start();
$userid = $_SESSION['userid'];
?>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function open_win()
{
window.open("http://www.mysite.com/exams/print.php?uid_print=$userid",'','width=200,height=100')
}
</script>
</head>
<?php
if ($_SESSION['auth']) {  
include 'datalogin.php';

echo "<input type='button' value='Print this page' onclick='open_win()' />";
```

**Page2(print.php)**

```
<?php
session_start();
include 'datalogin.php';
$uid_print1 = $_GET['uid_print'];

echo $uid_print1;
```

But my ouput is:  $userid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the moment the variable in your javascript tag is not replaced because it is not enclosed by PHP tags. You can easily do it like this:

```
window.open("http://www.mysite.com/exams/print.php?uid_print=<?php echo $userid; ?>",'', 'width=200,height=100')
```

Answer (score 4):

```
window.open("http://www.mysite.com/exams/print.php?uid_print=&lt;?php echo $userid; ?>",'','width=200,height=100')
```

Answer (score 2):

Modify your `window.open` line to looks like this:

```
window.open("http://www.mysite.com/exams/print.php?uid_print=<?php echo $userid; ?>",'','width=200,height=100');
```

You have to 'enter' PHP block, and print out `$userid` variable to HTML (JavaScript) output.

Answer (score 2):

This line in your JS script:

```
window.open("http://www.mysite.com/exams/print.php?uid_print=$userid",'','width=200,height=100')
```

Outputs '$userid' directly. You need to replace $userid with something like:

```
<?php echo $userid; ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `<?php....?>` tags:

```
...print.php?uid_print=<?php echo $userid;?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Replacing:

```
window.open("http://www.mysite.com/exams/print.php?uid_print=$userid",'','width=200,height=100')
```

With:

```
window.open("http://www.mysite.com/exams/print.php?uid_print=<?php echo $userid; ?>",'','width=200,height=100')
```

Should probably do the trick.

You can also use the [shorthand](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag) `<?= $userid ?>` which, to my eyes is more readable.

Answer (score 2):

please concatenate $userid in your javascript.

it can be concatenated like uid_print='.$userid.' and you will get the value in $_GET["uid_print"]

you can also echo the $userid in string like